# Angular.js render template in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, mustache

I'm trying to make Angular.js to render a template that contains a template. The essentials are as follows:

In controller:

```
$scope.templates['idOfTmpl'] = '<div>{{someAttribute}}</div>'
```

In view:

```
{{templates['idOfTmpl']}}
```

This literary results in the following *text* in the browser (including the divs):

```
<div>{{someAttribute}}</div>
```

And when inspecting the text we see this in the DOM tree:

```
"<div>{{someAttribute}}</div>"
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to make Angular render my template in a template?

Background: I am migrating an application using Mustache.js where one might use tripple brackets to tell the templating engine to render the text in the rendered text.

View in Mustanche.js:

```
{{{templates['idOfTmpl']}}}
```

Comment: why don't you use directives with templates instead? the directive may contain own templates, which you can even save in html files. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive In such directives you may use again variables like {{someAttribute}}

Comment: I used <div ng-bind="{{templates[alarm.icon.type]}}"></div>. This produces the exact same result as <div>{{templates[alarm.icon.type]}}</div>. The template within the template does not get compiled, only printed literally as text.